# How can I disable creepers' block damage on my Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Please note that **these are NOT acceptable solutions**:

- Completely disabling monsters (peaceful mode)
- Completely removing creepers
- Completely disabling explosions (TNT + Creepers)
- Disabling creeper explosions

More exactly, I want the creepers to be able to spawn and explode, but without doing their terrain damage (they should still be doing health damage to the players).

I'm fine with the use of mods but I'd prefer a built-in solution if possible.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's now built into 1.4.5 (and perhaps earlier 1.4.x). This is a command built into the server, and also single-player, if you have cheats enabled.

> /gamerule mobGriefing false

Exactly as you want: creepers damage players but not blocks.

As a bonus, I just installed the "Ice Cream Sandwich Creeper Mod" -- in snow biome, creeper explosions leave ... well, just as the name implies. There's also full crafting support.

Comment: Be aware that with mobGriefing disabled, villagers won't farm anymore.

Comment: Also, endermen don't pick blocks.

Comment: Is it possible to deactive environmental damage only for Creepers? I ask because for example redstone sheep farms and other things won't work too, since sheep eat the grass but the block won't change.

Answer (score 29):

With WorldGuard you can!

Download this [Bukkit Mod](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/sec-worldguard-5-2-block-fire-ice-melt-mushrooms-advanced-fast-area-protect-blacklist-1000.790/) and install it

Then in the config.yml file

change the line with

```
block-creeper-block-damage = true
```

to

```
block-creeper-block-damage = false
```

With this no damage will be made to your blocks but it will to players :D

Answer (score 9):

The [CreeperHeal](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/sec-creeperheal-v3-0-2-repair-damage-done-by-creepers-explosions-and-fire-after-a-while-1000.22476/) mod for bukkit enables creeper explosions with a twist: the blocks grow back over time (within 30 seconds, usually).

Comment: Hey, Domocus, I think something like this would better serve as a comment, as you haven't actually answered the question.

Comment: You may be referring to [CreeperHeal](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/sec-creeperheal-v3-0-2-repair-damage-done-by-creepers-explosions-and-fire-after-a-while-1000.22476/).

Comment: But if someone falls into the hole and the blocks respawn... he will sufficate. :S

Comment: Well then dont fall into the hole obviously! (oh, and they fixed that too)