# How Can I Stop Creepers Destroying Blocks On Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disable creepers block damage on my Minecraft server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27884/how-can-i-disable-creepers-block-damage-on-my-minecraft-server)
>   [Removing some hostile creatures in minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82541/removing-some-hostile-creatures-in-minecraft)

Hello fellow minecrafters, I am making an adventure map with lots of fighting mobs in it, and I was wondering if there was a way to stop creepers from destroying the map (for obvious reasons.)

Comment: Welcom to Arqade! I edited out the second question, but you can probably find the answer in one of these questions if you aren't looking for a mod: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9344/what-are-the-properties-of-fire http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10270/what-is-the-minimum-safe-spacing-between-trees-to-contain-forest-fires

Comment: @Wikwocket: It seems like he's asking more if it's possible to have creepers, just not have them destroy the landscape.

Comment: @Ullallulloo I agree, but the question I linked did have the solution in an answer. The "How can I disable creepers block damage" is a better match though; glad some people linked that one.

Answer (score 8):

You can set `/gamerule mobGriefing false`. This will also prevent Wither damage, Ghast damage, crop trampling and Endermen moving blocks. This works in singleplayer too.

Comment: Cheating isn't an answer, is it?